# Random space inside form

Tags: html, forms, html-table

I'm making a form for my website and there's an empty space in between the first label and input. When I remove the label, everything goes back to normal but I'd like to use the label. Thanks in advance to anyone that can help.

```
<form id="contactForm">
<div class="tableRow">
<p><label for="name">Name</label></p>
</p><input type="text" name="name"></input><p>
</div>
<div class="tableRow">
<p><label for="email">Email</label></p>
<p><input type="email" name="email"></input></p>
</div>
<div class="tableRow">
<p><label for="comments">Comments</label></p>
<p><textarea cols="48" rows="10" name="comments"></textarea></p>
</div>
</form>
```

and here's my css

```
#contactForm{
margin: 0 auto;
display: table;
}

.tableRow{
display: table-row;
}

.tableRow p{
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: top;
}

.tableRow p:first-child{
text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Can you give some jsfiddle demo to explain what you really mean?

Comment: Also the for attribute should be equal to the id of the element and not name.

Comment: Could you possibly explain what the attribute is?

Comment: An HTML attribute is a modifier of an HTML element. In this case I mean that for="name" should be linked to the input by providing id="name" to the input. Both the id and for are called attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your P tag

```
</p><input type="text" name="name"></input><p>
```

should be

```
<p><input type="text" name="name"></input></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
 </p><input type="text" name="name"></input><p>
```

you have just placed  the closing p tag fist

just change it to

```
<p><input type="text" name="name"></input></p>
```

check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/G2xRA/35/)